# Конский вопрос

Tags: значение-слов, словообразование

Ребёнок спросил, глядя в окно трамвая: "А как называется вон тот маленький островок на реке?" Я подумал, и ответил так: "Ну, вон тот, большой, называется Конный. А этот, поменьше, наверное, будет тогда Собачий".

А потом подумал: если бы остров был "Конский", тогда аналогия "Собачий" была бы правильна. Например, конский навоз и собачье, гм... А что бывает "конное"? Например, конный спорт. Или конная тяга. А если это не конная, а собачья повозка, - можно ли сказать "собачья тяга"?

Допустима ли аналогия "конный" - "собачий"? Или надо какой-нибудь "собакин" придумать? Вот, вспомнил, бывает ещё *псовая охота*. Может быть, и остров тогда можно назвать *Псовым*?

Answer (score 1):

Аналогии между парами собачий-псовый и конный-конский нет. Разделение произошло по разным причинам и относится к разной семантической мотивации.

Собачий-псовый просто отражает наличие древнего и более современного  синонима (пес - собака соответственно), а конный-конский - это разные вещи.

//==== 
Словарь трудностей

Назад 
Конный и конский

Вопрос
Как лучше: конная или конская выставка?

Прилагательное конный имеет следующие значения:
относящийся к коню, предназначенный для коней, их содержания, служащий для езды на конях. Конная площадь, ярмарка, ряд (место, где торгуют лошадьми). Конный завод (хозяйство по разведению коней). Конная упряжка. Конный двор. Конная дорога. Конный спорт;
действующий с помощью коней, приводимый в движение конями: Конная тяга.
едущий верхом на коне. Конные бойцы. Конный ратник. Конного гостя провожай до коня, а пешего до ворот (посл.).
состоящий из всадников, из конницы. Конная армия. Конный строй.
Прилагательное конский имеет следующие значения:
относящийся к коню, принадлежащий, свойственный ему; лошадиный. Конский топот.   Конский волос. Конский хвост. Конские состязания. Конская скачка. Конский завод (то же, что конный завод). Конская ярмарка (то же, что конная ярмарка).
как составная часть некоторых ботанических названий. Конский каштан. Конский щавель. Конские бобы.
В словарях зафиксировано как словосочетание конная ярмарка, так и конская ярмарка. Однако прилагательное конский в современном русском языке, в отличие от конный, имеет более узкую сферу, а именно — употребляется в составе специальных словосочетаний. Словосочетание конная выставка предпочтительно, так как сфера употребления прилагательного конный достаточно широка.

Различай
конский и конный.
//====

http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/trudnosti/36_166

> А если это не конная, а собачья повозка, - можно ли сказать "собачья тяга"?

В ироническом смысле - вполне. Просто конная тяга подразумевает некое промышленное использование. Собак в подобных целях не эксплуатируют. Сани (ключая нарты и проч.) бывают на **собачьем ходу**.

Псовая охота - это не более чем традиция. Вполне допустимо (как сейчас и делают многие не искушенные в таких тонкостях люди) собачья охота.

//-------------

Граждане, прошу меня извинить, но мое чаша моего терпения местным редактором окончательно переполнилась. Тратить по десять минут на редактирование каждого поста с копипастом - это уже слишком. Смотрите по ссылке, если что.

Comment: Может быть, тогда уж не в ироническом, а в ругательном смысле? Ну, как "собачья погода"?

Comment: Да, и "конская скачка", я бы сказал, тоже звучит достаточно двусмысленно. Вроде как "достал уже этот конский эдобовский интерфейс!" - часто слышу такое словоупотребление ("конский" == "очень неудобный, некачественный").

Comment: Можно и в ругательном. Но это - другое.

Я немного не о том. Если речь идет о санях, действительно движимых собачьей упряжкой, то "собачья тяга" будет выражением ироническим, поскольку "тяга" здесь стилистически неуместно.  

"Конская тяга" и тяга вообще используется во фразах "конка - трамвай на конской тяге", "пресс на конской тяге", "тягловая лошадь" и проч. Т.е. это не просто сани/телега, это что-то в промышленных или массовых масштабах,  как минимум - плуг. Собаки для таких механизмов пока не используются. Они бывают **ездовые**, никак не тягловые.  
Отсюда и ирония в "собачьей тяге".

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, "конский" имеет более конкретное отношение непосредственно к лошадям, а "конный" — больше к коневодству в целом. Таким образом "конский хвост", но "конный спорт" или Конный рынок в Харькове.

Comment: Ну, в таком случае,какое определение могло бы иметь отношение больше к "собаководству" в целом, а не непосредственно с собакам?

Answer (score 0):

Конный - это имеющий коня. Соответственно имеющий собаку - *собачный, особаченный*, но оба слова не особо употребительны. Можно *собаководный*, но не звучит, да и оттенок несколько иной, к нему скорее конезаводный подходит.

Учитывая, что упряжка бывает *конной* и *собачьей*, ваша аналогия вполне уместна.

Comment: Ну, если уж дошли до "собаководный", тогда уж уместнее будет "кинологический".